# PDI - Microsoft Excel Writer - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using PDI to generate a Excel.xslx file in a folder using Microsoft Excel Writer component and I'm trying to read this file from a microservice. The problem is I can't read because the file is with permissions: -rw-r-----. How can I write the file with permissions to everyone or how can I change this permissions in PDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an user "pentaho", put the service to run in the same docker and with the same user.

Dockerfile Pentaho:

```
...

RUN cd /pentaho && \
  rm /pentaho/*server*/promptuser.sh; \
  sed -i -e 's/\(exec ".*"\) start/\1 run/' /pentaho/*server*/tomcat/bin/startup.sh; \
  mkdir /home/pentaho && groupadd -r pentaho && useradd -r -g pentaho -p $(perl -e'print crypt("pentaho", "aa")' ) -G sudo pentaho && \ 
  chown -R pentaho.pentaho /pentaho && \ 
  chown -R pentaho.pentaho /home/pentaho

WORKDIR /pentaho
USER pentaho


EXPOSE 8080
```

Dockerfile App:

```
FROM    company/pentaho:1.0.0
MAINTAINER  Company

ADD start_scripts/run.sh /pentaho/

...
RUN sudo chown -R pentaho.pentaho /pentaho/pentaho-server

WORKDIR /pentaho
USER pentaho


EXPOSE 8080

# 1. Run 

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/pentaho/run.sh"]
```

Run.sh:

```
if [ -z "$DEBUG" ]; then
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in DEBUG mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar sheet-service.jar & 
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho.sh;
else
  echo Starting Sheet Formatting service and Pentaho in normal mode
  cd /pentaho/
  java -jar sheet-service.jar &
  cd *server*
  ./start-pentaho-debug.sh;
fi
```